SwiftUI: Programmatically scroll one long Text
Usually when you have text in a scrollview, pressing spacebar will scroll down to the next piece of text, usually the part that is just beyond the visible part of the scrollview comes up. for example if your string ends up as 9 lines for the given size of the scroll view and line 1,2,3 are visible, then we want to press one button to scroll and show 4,5,6.
I am looking for a way to do this in SwiftUI.  It has to adapt to the current size of the scrollview.
Here is a barebones example of the scrollview I have.
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                Text(longText)
            }
            
            Button("next") {
                // Make it scroll a little
            }
        }
    }

    var longText = """
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis. Et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer eget. Arcu non odio euismod lacinia. Ipsum a arcu cursus vitae. Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat. Ut eu sem integer vitae justo eget. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec dui nunc. Aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor. Eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel. Velit egestas dui id ornare. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra. Est sit amet facilisis magna.
    """
}

I have tried .scrollPosition(id:) but that requires setting an id.  Since there is only one Text object it wouldn't go anywhere.

is this for macOS or ios devices?

This can be solved by using placeholders in the background that have the size of a single page. Then you can use scrollPosition to scroll to the next/previous placeholder.
A GeometryReader surrounding the ScrollView can be used to measure the height of the ScrollView. Another GeometryReader in the background of the Text can be used to measure the height of the Text. The number of pages/placeholders can then be calculated from the two heights.
The updated example below works on both macOS and iOS, but the keyboard shortcuts are probably only useful on macOS:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var nPages = 0
    @State private var currentPage: Int? = 0

    private var pageButtons: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("previous") {
                if (currentPage ?? 0) > 0 {
                    withAnimation {
                        currentPage = (currentPage ?? nPages - 1) - 1
                    }
                }
            }
            .keyboardShortcut(KeyboardShortcut("-", modifiers: []))

            Spacer()

            Button("next") {
                if (currentPage ?? 0) < nPages - 1 {
                    withAnimation {
                        currentPage = (currentPage ?? 0) + 1
                    }
                }
            }
            .keyboardShortcut(KeyboardShortcut(.space, modifiers: []))
        }
        .padding()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            GeometryReader { outer in
                let scrollHeight = outer.size.height
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    Text(longText)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .background {
                            GeometryReader { proxy in
                                let textHeight = proxy.size.height
                                let numPages = (textHeight / max(1, scrollHeight)) + 1
                                Color.clear
                                    .onChange(of: numPages, initial: true) { oldVal, newVal in
                                        nPages = Int(newVal)
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                        .background {
                            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                                ForEach(0..<nPages, id: \.self) { pageNum in
                                    Color.clear
                                        .frame(maxHeight: scrollHeight)
                                }
                            }
                            .scrollTargetLayout()
                        }
                }
                .scrollPosition(id: $currentPage, anchor: .top)
            }
            pageButtons
        }
    }

    var longText = """
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis. Et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer eget. Arcu non odio euismod lacinia. Ipsum a arcu cursus vitae. Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat. Ut eu sem integer vitae justo eget. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec dui nunc. Aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor. Eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel. Velit egestas dui id ornare. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra. Est sit amet facilisis magna.
    """
}


You will notice that it does not scroll a complete page at a time. This is because, the number of pages is not an exact integer number and maxHeight has been used to set the placeholder height. Doing it this way, the full height of the text is divided into equal height sections and stepping to next/previous scrolls by the same amount every time.
If you would prefer that it scrolls a full page at a time (until the last), then apply the background with alignment: .top and use height instead of maxHeight:
.background(alignment: .top) { //  HERE
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(0..<nPages, id: \.self) { pageNum in
            Color.clear
                .frame(height: scrollHeight) //  AND HERE
        }
    }
    .scrollTargetLayout()
}

